# why would someone plan to treat themself before throw off a tower?

Tags: lyrics, interpretation

I'm still puzzled by Gilbert O'Sullivan alone again lyrics, the part he says:

> If I'm not feeling any less sour
> I promised myself to treat myself
> And visit a nearby tower
> And climbing to the top
> Will throw myself off

why would his promise to treat himself before throw himself off a tower???

Comment: @MichaelHarvey marcelo is a new user here. Please be clear what the actual reason for voting to close is, and what's a joke.

Comment: It's bitterly ironic.

Answer (score 3):

The word "and" doesn't always conjoin two different things. Sometimes it means the second thing gives detail about the first thing.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/and) defines it:

> **and** *conjunction*
> **2 a** —used as a function word to express ... supplementary explanation

Here's the relevant parts of the quoted lyrics

> I promised myself to treat myself
> **And** visit a nearby tower

In this song, the word "and" indicates that visiting the tower is the supplementary explanation of "treat myself". It means the same as:

> I promised myself to treat myself **by visiting** a nearby tower

This means he is so depressed that going to the tower and jumping off it is the treat that will make him feel better!